# Half of my cylinders aren't firing. Is it safe to move my car to a garage (~30km)?

Tags: ignition, catalytic-converter, gasoline

I am having some issue with my ECU or ignition system which I can't fix myself. Only two of my four cylinders are firing. Is it safe to drive my car to the official mechanic at 30km distance? Should I unplug the injectors of the non-firing cylinders to prevent gas from entering and leaving the cylinders and entering/damaging my catalytic converter?

Comment: What car is it?

Comment: It's a 2001 Mitsubishi Colt EDM (german version) 1.3 16V hatchback.

Comment: AKA Mirage in some places.

Comment: Ah, I thought you may be able to fix the problem yourself, but I can't figure out where your coilpack is on the engine. I mean, I know where it's supposed to be, but it doesn't look as simple to change as on some of my cars.

Comment: Already checked the coils :) It's not an easy fix unfortunately. The two cylinders that aren't firing, are connected to different coils. I already checked the sparkplugs, coils, wiring and compression.

Answer (score 4):

I would personally avoid it as you'll be putting some very odd stresses on the engine and the heat generated will be non-uniform too.  For the sake of arranging recovery or even finding a friend with a straight bar or even just a sturdy piece of rope, I don't think it's worth potentially ruining your engine.

Answer (score 2):

Beneath the stress mentioned by @SteveMatthews, there is another problem.
A larger amount of unburnt fuel in your exhaust system will damage your catalytic converter. I guess driving 30km with just half the cylinders fireing will be enough to kill the converter.

Comment: I had a confined cat fire (melted it into blocking the exhaust) just after having a power transistor fail and rolling to a stop (injectors still firing).

Comment: How about if I unplug the injectors for the cylinders that aren't working?

Comment: Hmm, then you don't get unburnt fuel from that cylinders. But the excess of oxygen measured by the lambda sensor will cause a much richer mixture in the remaining cylinders, so still some partially unburnt fuel. I don't know how much it will be, and how dangerous it is for the converter.